# Not able to access media file even if file exists when checked manually

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, media

I have a media file that Django isn't able to access, even if it definitely exists if I enter its URL in the browser.

## Info

1. **Language**: Python [v.3.9.7]
2. **Platform**: Django [v.3.2.8]

## Goal

Being able to access the media file

## Description

The thing is, people can upload books on my website. People upload images of these books in different sizes, so I want to be able to handle all of them, so I access the width and height of the image and then use that as the size of the image in the view (CSS). To do that, I've used a custom filter `image_size` that is going to do all the work of accessing the image and finding its size, which I send back to the view:

```
@register.filter
def image_size(img, host):
    img = host[0] + "://" + host[1] + img
    with Image.open(img) as image:
        width, height = image.size
        dct = {
            "width": width,
            "height": height
        }
        return dct
```

Here, `host[0]` is the protocol (`request.scheme`) of the URL of the image and `host[1]` is the host name (`request.get_host()`). Here's my view:

```
def all_books(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = {
            "books": Book.objects.all(),
            "request": request,
            "user_profile": UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user),
            "mail_sent": False,
        }
    else:
        context = {
            "books": Book.objects.all(),
            "request": request,
            "mail_sent": False,
            "user_profile": False,
        }
    context["host"] = [request.scheme, request.get_host()]
    if request.GET.get("context") == "mail_sent":
        context["mail_sent"] = True
    return render(request, 'main/all_books.html', context)
```

**settings.py static and media config**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_URL = '/main/user_login/'
```

Where `BASE_DIR` is `Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent` (`Path` is imported from `pathlib`)

I *haven't* done `collectstatic` because for some reason it removes connection to CSS and suddenly no CSS is rendered.

What should I do to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploaded files go to MEDIA_ROOT unless it is defined differently in the model field
You build the path to the img file "manually" in the filter ... which does not point to media/...

```
img = host[0] + "://" + host[1] + img
```

I do not know what you hand in as 'img' but here it looks like the string is just

```
img = "https://my_serverm_image"
```

But on the server you need lokal path depending on your operating system e.g. c:/my_project/media on windows.
That path is stored in settings.MEDIA_ROOT.
So a correct string could be:

```
img =  settings.MEDIA_ROOT + img
```

Comment: I didn't understand you. The code you have suggested is the same as I've done...

Comment: I wanted to point you just to the critical line of code. I cant see what you handover to that filter as img. But for the moment the resulting img string seems to be sth like "http://servermyimage" which does not include media. I would sujest to print the string and check

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. The rsulting `img` is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/book_thumbnails/the-lord-of-the-rings-fellowhip-of-the-ring_LjgKcIR.jpeg`

Comment: The code you added in your edit was exactly what I needed. I've done this:

Comment: `img = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, img.split('media/')[1])`

Comment: The older `img` (before I added `MEDIA_ROOT`) was `book.thumbnail.url` which I got from the template, so it included `media/` at the beginning, so all I did was remove that and keep the rest. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: See my edited answer above. Img.open() needs a lokal path

Comment: Yes, I knew that, but then I understood what was wrong with my code when I saw your answer again, thanks